# Can I kill two enemies with one bullet?

Tags: far-cry-3

Can projectiles pass through enemies? If yes, what weapons allow this? How does the damage work? Will the impact on the first enemy hit by the projectile, lessen damage to the second enemy hit?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okay here's a list of all (non unlockable) guns and if they penetrate the enemy.

Handguns:

```
 - 1911           No penetration
 - 6P9            Penetration
 - .44 Magnum     Penetration
 - D50            Penetration
```

Smg's:

```
- Skorpion        No penetration
- A2000           No penetration
- MP5             Penetration
- BZ19            Penetration
- Vector .45      Penetration
```

Shotguns:

```
- M133            Penetration (Possibly)
- 1887            Penetration
- Spas-12         Penetration
```

Assault Rifles:

```
- Ak-47           Penetration
- Stg-90          Penetration
- F1              Penetration
- Ms16            Penetration
- P416            Penetration
- Ace             Penetration
```

Snipers:

```
-  SVD            Penetration
-  M-700          Penetration
-  Z93            Penetration
```

LMG's:

```
- PKM             Penetration
- U100            Penetration
- MKG             Penetration
```

Just as an extra the recurve bow arrows do not pass trough enemies.

I didnt include the launchers for obvious reasons. Also the special unlockable weapons because they are just upgrades from other guns

Comment: Nice research. I was surprised that almost every weapon can shoot ammunition that pass through enemies. I initially thought that this can only be done on sniper rifles and other high-powered guns.

Comment: Yeah so was I. I do have to say i did this by lining 2 heads up so I could go for 2 headshots so if you do not shoot 2 headshots the amount of damage might be neglectable compared to normal fire. But if I wanted to compare damage after penetration I would still be shooting rakyat in their cars.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is possible.
While sneaking up upon an outpost I was able to line up the heads of two enemies. I shot one bullet with the M-700, yet both ended up dead.
With the Z93 you are able to kill multiple enemies with one shot, even if you don't get the head of either one, as long as they aren't heavy armored LMG/flamethrower enemies. With LMG/flamethrower enemies you will still need to hit the head.

I suspect that there are more weapons that will at least allow double-headshots with one bullet. Any sniper, assault rifle and LMG should have a high enough caliber for the bullets to pass through enemies. High caliber pistols like the D50 and the .44 Magnum should do the same.

I have no idea however if the damage is lessend with the second hit.

*Edit:*
The Recursive Bow's arrows will not pass through enemies. The arrows (as long as they are not explosive/flammable ones) will stick to the body and can sometimes be picked up from it for re-use.
Any explosive or flammable projectile will also not pass through enemies, like rockets or grenade-launcher-grenades, which is pretty logical. They do have the ability to kill multiple enemies though, which is also pretty logical.

Comment: i can confirm that with snipers you can indeed kill multiple people in 1 shot

Comment: Aside from the sniper rifles, can anyone confirm which other weapons have projectiles that pass through enemies? What about the Recurve Bow?

Comment: The Recurve Bow's arrows don't pass through enemies. They stick to the corpse and can sometimes be picked up from it for reuse. I'll edit this in my answer.

Comment: @galacticninja i'm bored ill go test out what weapons pass through more than 1 person

Comment: @SergeBekenkamp Remember to answer/comment back here with your results. =)

Answer (score 0):

Snipers don't kill two people with one shot. It's ruined my undetected bonus many times. It only kills the first guy. I've tried many times, with a special sniper as well as with regular snipers, and I failed every time.

Comment: Not killing is not equal to not penetrating.

Comment: "*Snipers don't kill two people with one shot*" Do you mean if it's a body shot (and not a headshot)? (If yes, please edit this in your answer.) Could you edit in the names of the (special/regular) sniper rifles that you have tried, too?

Comment: Killing two enemies with a sniper worked me with the M-700, when their heads line up. With the Z93 just the bodies lining up also worked perfectly fine, so it's quite clear to me that at least some weapon's bullets do indeed penetrate. For your issue of not beeing able to kill the second enemy, could that be dependant on difficulty?